# Displaying JLabel movement

Tags: java, swing, animation, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I am attempting to create a simple animation in which a series of bubble rotate around a centre point. I have one version of animation where the bubbles spread from the centrepoint before they begin to rotate, which works fine, but as soon as I click one of the images (which sparks the animation) the screen freezes for a moment and then the bubbles appear in their end position, rather than showing each step they made.

What I have so far is:

```
    while(bubble[1].getDegree() != 270) 
    { 
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        //the below if statement contains the function calls for
        //the rotating bubble animations.
        next();
        draw();

        //  delay for each frame  -   time it took for one frame 
        time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time); 

        if (time > 0) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                Thread.sleep(time); 
            } 
            catch(Exception e){} 
        }
    }


public void draw()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < bubble.length; i++)
    {   
        iconLabel[i].setLocation(bubble[i].getX(), bubble[i].getY());
        textLabel[i].setLocation((bubble[i].getX()+10),(bubble[i].getY()+10));
    }

}
```

For clarity, the method "next()" merely changes the position of the bubble to the appropriate place, I know this to be functioning as I have had the animation work before but once I implemented the animation to JLabels it stopped working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawing is frozen because you block the event dispatch thread. Drawing is done in the same thread as the `while` loop, and since the loop prevents anything else happening while it's running, swing can get to drawing only after the loop is finished, so only the last position is drawn.

Use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead:

```
timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // whatever you need for the animation
        updatePositions();
        repaint();
    }
});
timer.start();
```

And then call `timer.stop()` when all the frames you need have been processed.